# How can I redraw a circle in html5 with retaining the visibility of the previous circle path

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm tring to draw an expanding and contracting ring that pulses using javascript and html 5. The problem is (using the below code) when the path is repainted the current path remains visible and just gets fatter. Anybody know why this could be?

```
 function drawOuterInfoCircle(){
     var number = 25;
     var increase = true;

     function draw(){
         if(increase==true){
             number++
             //alert('increase');
             if(number==30){
                 increase=false
                 }
             }           
         if(increase==false){
             number--;
             //alert('decrease');
             if(number==25){
                 increase=true
             }
         }               
         var drawingCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas_circle');
         var drawingContext1 = drawingCanvas.getContext('2d');
         drawingContext1.strokeStyle = "#990000";
         drawingContext1.lineWidth = 12;
         drawingContext1.beginPath();
         drawingContext1.arc(100, 100, number, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
         drawingContext1.closePath();
         drawingContext1.stroke();       
     }
     setInterval(draw,100);      
 }
```

I've tried clearing the canvas with the following (from post 3088229) tna

```
drawingContext1.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)';    
drawingContext1.fill();
```

**the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QVAVV/)**

Comment: You might find using HTML5 SVG a better option for this.

Comment: Whys that Steve. Does it remove the need to refill the same area? Cheers for the heads up BTW - i'll check it out

Comment: Instead of drawing a bitmap, erasing the canvas and redrawing it, you can create an SVG object and then change it's properties and it will redisplay itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are filling with opacity 0, try `rgba(0,0,0,1)`

Comment: Thanks - it would also help if I set the colour to white aswell :) off to hang my head in shame now

Comment: NP. Like Steve has commented, SVG might be a better fit for your purpose. Also look at libraries like D3.js, which make animating SVG a breeze.

Answer (score 0):

before each ring drawing erase the older canvas and redraw on it,

```
function draw(){


    var drawingCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas_circle');
    var drawingContext1 = drawingCanvas.getContext('2d');
    drawingContext1.clearRect(0,0,drawingCanvas_width,drawingCanvas_height);


     if(increase==true){
         number++
         //alert('increase');
         if(number==30){
             increase=false
             }
         }           
     if(increase==false){
         number--;
         //alert('decrease');
         if(number==25){
             increase=true
         }
     }               
     //var drawingCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas_circle');
     //var drawingContext1 = drawingCanvas.getContext('2d');
     drawingContext1.strokeStyle = "#990000";
     drawingContext1.lineWidth = 12;
     drawingContext1.beginPath();
     drawingContext1.arc(100, 100, number, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
     drawingContext1.closePath();
     drawingContext1.stroke();       
 }
```